# Java ListView class?

Tags: java, android, xml

What is the difference between a  listview layout xml and a Listview Java class? I am trying to make it when a user inputs text and presses enter it comes on a set position on the right but when the user receives a reply it would show up on the left side of the list view. Like text messaging on android phones. Does anyone know how i can do this? With a java class or an xml layout? I want animations and dynamic content on the listview as well. Any ideas?

Comment: What you have done, show us your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

`ListActivity` provides you all the built-in features of and methods of `ListView` but only `ListView` can be added into the whole `Activity`. By using `ListView` in xml, you add multiple Views such as `Buttons`, `EditText` on the same `Activity`.

Comment: This isn't the case, you can use other widgets also with `ListActivity` as you can use in simple `Activity` with `ListView`, and this really doesn't answer the question which OP is asking.

Comment: I never see this, BTW how to add other widgets in ListActivity.

Comment: So what is the answer? Xml Listview or Java listview is prefered? because i know xml Listview is easier to do.

Comment: Adil Soomro would give you better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the xml is for seperating the design (the visuals) from the code (functionality).
Although you can do some funcationality via xml, it's usually better to do it in Java code in your class.

I guess you can create a ListView that will iterate through 2 different list enteries:

The first will show the data (the text in your case) on left and the second entry will show on the right. For each list entery you will create a different xml layout with widgets aligned to the left and right as needed.